# How to send value through Button in materializecss?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, materialize

When I click on this button, modal1 will be open but I want to send data through this button which can be access in modal any appropriate solution ?

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger red darken-1" href="#modal1">Buy Now</a>
```

Comment: how does this relate to java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simplistic approach would be to make use of [HTML5 data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). All you need to do is to add `data-key="value"` in your button. You can then access this data in your modal by using jquery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

You can refer this [codepen](http://codepen.io/pratikms/pen/XdPwRO) for getting a better idea on how to use data-attributes.